# How to Convert const char * name to char uint8_t in C

Tags: c, global-variables

I have a global variable `static constant uint8_t username[] = "Hello"`
and a local variable `const char * name = "chill"`.

How can I update the global variable value from hello to chill?

I tried `atoi`, but it only works for integers and most solutions were for C++ which recommended using objects.  Please show me the way to solve this using C programming?

Comment: Don't describe your code but show it. You can [edit] your question. But anyway why `atoi`? There is no `int` variable involved here...

Comment: What is `static constant`? Is this real code or pseudo code?

Comment: My question is also: why use a `uint8_t` in the first definition when you already initialize it with a (const) `char *`? If the intended use is simple text, even the first array can be just a `char []` one - I vaguely remember a CERT/MISRA/*some other* recommendation to do so

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `static constant uint8_t...` is a typo that should read: `static const uint8_t...`:

You can't because `username` is declared `const`.

If you drop the `const`, then you can use `strcpy`:

```
static uint8_t username[] = "Hello";
...
const char *name = "chill";
...
strcpy(username, name);
```

Disclaimer: there is no length check in this code, if `name` points to a string longer than the string "Hello" it is not going to end well because this will overwrite memory after `username`.

Comment: Maybe a `strncpy(username, name, sizeof(username)/sizeof(username[0])); username[sizeof(username)/sizeof(username[0])-1] = '\0';` would fit - or with an ARRAYSIZE() macro, if your system has it.

Comment: *Note* I didn't mention `strncpy_s` use, as its implementation is somewhat debated...

Comment: Code:-
static uint8_t username[] = "Hello"; // removed the constant here

int main()
{
//Some code that receives a json format from cloud and the value of ssid is //put into the variable name. 
const char *name = json_object_dotget_string(wifi, "ssid");

//I have checked that the value is received properly. Now i have to push this name value to global variable username[]. 

[I tried with integer values instead of Text, So i used atoi for type conversion to push value to a local variable. This worked fine.
uint8_t check = (uint8_t)atoi(name);
//Now i am testing with name as "chill".

Comment: @Nishith don't put code in comments (except short one liners), it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer but deleted it.

Whoever it is, thank you for the answer.
This below lines worked:

```
#define ARRAY_CARDINALITY(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x))
memcpy (username, name, ARRAY_CARDINALITY (username));
```

I have a additional question related to this. How to update global variable value in C if the data type is "char *". Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `username = name`, it depends. You absolutely need to understand the concept of "pointer". Please ask a new question and provide all details.